# .NET caching, weird behaviour

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching

In order to minimize the access to the database we're caching specific records using the following statement:

```
Cache("Article" & ArticleID) = objArticle
```

Where "ArticleID" is an integer variable, and objArticle is an object of type "Article" which has its own properties.

Sometimes a specific records is updated and in order to invalidate the cache, we're doing the following:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    Dim objArticle As Framework.BusinessLogic.Article
    If Cache("Article" & ArticleID) Is Nothing OrElse InvalidateCache = True Then
        If Not Cache("Article" & ArticleID) Is Nothing Then
            Cache.Remove("Article" & ArticleID)
        End If
        objArticle = New Framework.BusinessLogic.Article(ArticleID)
        Cache("Article" & ArticleID) = objArticle
    Else
        objArticle = Cache("Article" & ArticleID)
    End If
    ....
End If
```

The problem is that when an object is updated (also invalidated) users are reporting to see the different versions of the same object randomly, and a single user might see a different version on each refresh.

Please advise.

Best regards,
McHaimech

Comment: your code is not thread safe

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)
I guess I know how to solve it now.